# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: authenticator Ember js Error

Tags: ember.js

I got an error **ReferenceError: Can't find variable: authenticator Ember error** in browser console and *authenticator is not defined* in terminal with this code

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject } from '@ember/service';
export default Controller.extend({
  session: inject('session'),
   actions: {   
     authenticate: function(){
       var credentials = this.getProperties('username','password');
       authenticator = 'authenticator:jwt';
       this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator,credentials).catch((reason) => {
            this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
       });
     }
}
});
```

Comment: I have installed ember simple auth

Comment: You missed `var` keyword before `authenticator` to define that variable. Better use `let`.

Comment: @jelhan But I `var` or `let` is used when we create a user defined variable right?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jelhan said in the comments, you need to declare the variable `authenticator` by using let. This is a requirement of JavaScript and not anything specific to Ember.

Example:

import Controller from '@ember/controller';

```
import { inject } from '@ember/service';
export default Controller.extend({
  session: inject('session'),
   actions: {   
     authenticate: function(){
       var credentials = this.getProperties('username','password');
       let authenticator = 'authenticator:jwt';
       this.get('session').authenticate(authenticator,credentials).catch((reason) => {
            this.set('errorMessage', reason.error || reason);
       });
     }
}
});
```